# Handling KeyDown and KeyPress events in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-events

I'm trying to make a "keylogger"... well, it's not entirely a keylogger because it only displays the keystrokes and doesn't log them to a file. I was planning to use it on my Google+ Hangouts, so I can still show my keystrokes without having to use it with video recording software.

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    lblText.Text = "";
    lblText.Visible = false;

    boxSpKey.Image = null;
    boxSpKey.Visible = false;

    boxCtrl.Visible = e.Control;
    boxAlt.Visible = e.Alt;
    boxWin.Visible = false;
    boxShift.Visible = e.Shift;

    Keys pKey = e.KeyData;
    if (btnIcons.ContainsKey(pKey))
    {
        boxSpKey.Visible = true;
        boxSpKey.Image = btnIcons[pKey];
    }

    // this part I haven't figured out either, but is irrelevant to my question.
}

private void OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    lblText.Visible = true;
    lblText.Text = ((char)e.KeyChar).ToString();
}
```

[Context: `lblText` is a label containing the key text, `boxSpKey` is a `PictureBox` for special keys such as ESC, for which I've made each one an icon. `boxCtrl`, `boxAlt`, `boxWin` and `boxShift` are also `PictureBox`es are quite self-explanatory.]

Questions:

1. It seems that the values of `e.Control`, `e.Alt` and `e.Shift` are always False, so the respective `PictureBox`es wouldn't show up.
2. How do I check for the status of the `Win` key? I would prefer not to use low-level `VK_*` constants.
3. When `OnKeyPress` handles the events, mostly with the use of the modifier keys, I get random characters... How exactly do I get the original key strokes from them? i.e. I want to get `Ctrl+Shift+B` instead of `┐`.

---

**UPDATE**: I've decided to go low-level with the modifier keys, so I used P/Invoke:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);

public static byte code(Keys key)
{
    return (byte)((int)key & 0xFF);
}

private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var array = new byte[256];
    GetKeyboardState(array);

    // ...

    if ((array[code(Keys.ControlKey)] & 0x80) != 0)
        boxCtrl.Visible = true;
    if ((array[code(Keys.LMenu)] & 0x80) != 0 || (array[code(Keys.RMenu)] & 0x80) != 0)
        boxAlt.Visible = true;
    if ((array[code(Keys.LWin)] & 0x80) != 0 || (array[code(Keys.RWin)] & 0x80) != 0)
        boxWin.Visible = true;
    if ((array[code(Keys.ShiftKey)] & 0x80) != 0)
        boxShift.Visible = true;

    // ...
}
```

The good news is that I got the `Ctrl`, `Win` and `Shift` keys working, but not `Alt`; unless `Alt` ≠ `LMenu` and `RMenu`. What gives?

Comment: what about comparing against the e.Modifiers property using Keys, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx? See LWin and RWin for the Windows key.

Comment: Pressing the `Alt` key on my keyboard results in a `KeyCode` value of `Keys.Menu` in my handler.  It doesn't seem to distinguish between left and right. Unfortunately, I don't have another keyboard to test with.

Comment: @gowansg Odd... The keys `LMenu` and `RMenu` are supposed to check for the `Alt` keys on either side, but it seems that simply `Keys.Menu` works. Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd> individually caused `Control`, `Alt`, and `Shift` to return `true` in my `KeyDown` event handler.  Pressing each one of those keys individually resulted in `false` being returned in my `KeyUp` event handler.  Are you sure you're not handling the `KeyUp` event?
2. As @sean woodward said, <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> should map to either `Keys.LWin` or `Keys.RWin`
3. The `KeyPress` event is only raised when one of the character keys is pressed and will return the character that results from the pressed key or combination of pressed keys. `Ctrl+Shift+B` is not a character so you can't use `KeyChar` alone to get that information.  Try using the `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` event and looking at the `Modifiers` property to get a comma delimited string of which modifier keys are being pressed.  If order matters you'll need to track that as `Modifiers` always returns the keys in the same order, i.e. `Shift, Control, Alt` even if that's not how they were pressed.

Here is the code I used, you can try playing around with it:

```
KeyDown += (o, ea) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("KeyDown => CODE: " + ea.KeyCode +
        ", DATA: " + ea.KeyData +
        ", VALUE: " + ea.KeyValue +
        ", MODIFIERS: " + ea.Modifiers +
        ", CONTROL: " + ea.Control +
        ", ALT: " + ea.Alt +
        ", SHIFT: " + ea.Shift);

};

KeyUp += (o, ea) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("KeyUp => CODE: " + ea.KeyCode +
        ", DATA: " + ea.KeyData +
        ", VALUE: " + ea.KeyValue +
        ", MODIFIERS: " + ea.Modifiers +
        ", CONTROL: " + ea.Control +
        ", ALT: " + ea.Alt +
        ", SHIFT: " + ea.Shift);
};

KeyPress += (o, ea) => 
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("KeyPress => CHAR: " + ea.KeyChar);
};
```